# javascript setInterval function never runs

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a game that can be played against a software bot. Sometimes the bot can take a VERY long to decide its move. I am trying to add an indicator to the user that the bot is still 'thinking'. My simplified code looks like this:

```
function showThinking() {
    // spin a spinner or something
}

async function getBotChoices() {
    // lots of stuff including await getBotChoices() calls
    return stuff;
}

async function getBest() {
    // call the AI to get an array of choices (clicks)
    evalTimer = setInterval(showThinking, 1000);
    var choices = await getBotChoices();
    clearInterval(evalTimer);
}
```

All the game code works and I know getBest() runs. I put a breakpoint in showThinking but it never triggers. There are many cases where the code is spending 10+ seconds getting 'choices' from getBotChoices() which keeps a CPU pegged the entire time it runs. I feel like I'm missing some idea about the JS call stack but I'm not sure.

I could work around this by putting a counter in getBotChoices and updating the DOM every 'n' calls and get rid of the setInterval altogether but that seems so kludgey.
Any help is much appreciated.

@VLAZ explained the issue is the microqueue vs macroqueue and I think the larger answer is that the bot code should probably be run in a Web Worker (off to learn how they work!).

Comment: `getBotChoices()` most likely does synchronous operations that block the main thread. Therefore, it's not really asynchronous. You've probably added `async` to it expecting multithreading.

Comment: Does this need to be in an interval? Can you just toggle the visibility of a spinner before calling the bot's move and remove it after?

Comment: @VLAZ A single run of getBotChoices (ignoring the recursion) takes milliseconds. I thought when it called itself showThinking might run. Does it not BECAUSE I'm using await (which I need).

Comment: @SliceOfBread if you're doing recursion with just `await` before the recursive call, then you're just offloading to the microtask queue, which takes priority over the macrotask queue where the timers are scheduled. Effectively, still blocking the interval.

Comment: @Axekan I'm really trying to show that the code is actually running. For a user, it would be fine but for me the interval is kind of a watchdog timer.

Comment: Why not showThinking inside getBotChoices, or make another async function that wraps up showThinking, getBotChoices, remove showThinking.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah! That is where my understanding failed. That also explains the lack of responsiveness while it is running. I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @James That would be much more work than the kludge I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

@VLAZ pointed to the real issue here.

> if you're doing recursion with just await before the recursive call, then you're just offloading to the microtask queue, which takes priority over the macrotask queue where the timers are scheduled. Effectively, still blocking the interval. –
> VLAZ

Doing some more research on queue blocking, I think the answer is to move the bot code into a Web Worker. This will fix the real problem of the bot code blocking not just the setInterval but actually the entire page. In the Web Worker I will add the 'kludge' I described which will post messages back to the page every 'n' calls. The main page can just accumulate these and post updates as needed.